# I want to create a table like this ..I tried using multi-rows but i dont get the line bordering

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

```
\documentclass[times,twocolumn,final,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{framed,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline
S & & XXXX & RRRR \\
\hline
S1 & P \multirow{3}{*}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} \\
\cline{2-3}
 & & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4} \\ \cline{2-3}
 & & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{6} \\ \cline{2-3}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I wanted to create a table like that in figure. I tried using multi-rows, but I do not get the line bordering. How can I create a table with full bordering and grouping?

[image: Required Table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show us also the document in which  you tried `\multirows` etc.

Comment: If you could provide a minimal (not) working example (including only the main file and the table) where you point out the places that you couldn't solve it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LaTeX use `multirow` and `\cline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{S} & XX   & RRRR \\\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{S1} & P & 1    & 0.8  \\\cline{2-4}
                      & R & 0.8  & 0.3  \\\cline{2-4}
                      & F & 0.1  & 0.7  \\\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{S2} & P & 0.6  & 0.5  \\\cline{2-4}
                      & R & 0.6  & 0.2  \\\cline{2-4}
                      & F & 0.71 & 0.7  \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For fixed width columns, it is best to use the `array` package and declare a new column type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|C{1.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{2.5cm}|C{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{S} & XX   & RRRR \\\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{S1} & P & 1    & 0.8  \\\cline{2-4}
                      & R & 0.8  & 0.3  \\\cline{2-4}
                      & F & 0.1  & 0.7  \\\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{S2} & P & 0.6  & 0.5  \\\cline{2-4}
                      & R & 0.6  & 0.2  \\\cline{2-4}
                      & F & 0.71 & 0.7  \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.....I got the exact result...Thanks once again

Comment: @SubethaThankaraj If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Yeah sure.....I am new to this form ....I hope i have accepted and upvote the answer

Answer (score 1):

That is very easy to achieve with ConTeXt MKIV and Natural Tables.

```
\starttext

\startsetups table:multirows
  \setupTABLE[align={middle,lohi}]
  \setupTABLE[column][each][loffset=.5em,roffset=.5em]
\stopsetups
\startTABLE[setups={table:multirows}]
  \NC[nx=2] S        \NC XX   \NC RRRR \NC\NR
  \NC[ny=3] S1 \NC P \NC 1    \NC 0.8  \NC\NR
               \NC R \NC 0.8  \NC 0.3  \NC\NR
               \NC F \NC 0.1  \NC 0.7  \NC\NR
  \NC[ny=3] S2 \NC P \NC 0.6  \NC 0.5  \NC\NR
               \NC R \NC 0.6  \NC 0.2  \NC\NR
               \NC F \NC 0.71 \NC 0.7  \NC\NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Hi...Thank you so much for your reply.. I am using this table in my journal and i am getting error for the above code when i run...

Comment: @SubethaThankaraj You are most probably not using ConTeXt if you want to submit to a journal.  See my other answer for a LaTeX solution.